# jQuery Sliding Sidebars

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I'm working on a bit of jquery that will slide in 2 100% sidebars on either side of the window on hover (there's a 10px overlay region).

I can get it to work if either bar is hard-coded, however, I'm trying to combine code and when I do that the script doesn't work. I'm not sure if it has to do with passing values into the .animate() function or what. I'm not getting any error messages in my console.

Here's a Fiddle with the code: http://jsfiddle.net/u3XGF/

OR maybe it's something simple someone will spot right away:

**HTML**

```
<div id="sb-left" class="sidebar"></div>
<div id="workspace">
<div id="sb-right" class="sidebar"></div>​
```

**CSS**

```
html, body { width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: hidden; }

.sidebar { position: absolute; height: 100%; z-index: 99; }
.sidebar#sb-left { width: 300px; left: -290px; background: red; }
.sidebar#sb-right { width: 175px; right: -165px; background: green; }

#workspace { margin: 0 10px; height: 100%; background: #1a1a1a; z-index: 1; }
```

**JQuery**

```
$(function(){

  $('.sidebar').each(function(){

    // Slide
    if($(this).attr('id')=='sb_left'){ var side='left'; var width=300; var push_margin='margin-left'; }
    else{ var side='right'; var width=175; var push_margin='margin-right'; }

    $(this).hover(function() {
        var timeout = $(this).data("timeout");
        if(timeout){ clearTimeout(timeout); }
        $(this).animate({side:'0px'},300,'easeOutQuart');
        $('#workspace').animate({push_margin:width+'px'},300,'easeOutQuart');
     },function() {
        $(this).data("timeout", setTimeout($.proxy(function() {
            $(this).animate({side:'-'+(width-10)+'px'},300,'easeOutQuart');
            $('#workspace').animate({push_margin:'10px'},300,'easeOutQuart');
        },this), 300));
     });

  });

});​
```

Comment: using `hover` within a `each` method is not efficient.

Comment: Good to know, is that related to my question?

Comment: yes, because the hover won't fire as expected.

Comment: So, any suggestions on a better structure?

Comment: console.log on the hover function seems to show it firing fine.

Comment: there is no need for each method, you can write it like `$('.sidebar').hover(function(){...})`